# Подмена получаемого пакета от сервера

Tags: http, wireshark

Есть программа, которая отправляет запрос на сервер и получает ответ (например: `"coins=100"`).

Как сделать так, чтобы программа получала измененный ответ (например: `"coins=999999"`)?

Я знаю, что можно это сделать через breakpoint в charles, но там это работает не автоматически, а мне нужна именно авто-подмена ответа от сервера, потому что данная программа автоматически отправляет запросы примерно каждые 5 минут.

Какие есть программы для решения этой задачи, и как в них это можно реализовать?
Может быть это можно сделать в charles? Если можно, то как?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена, с помощью charles. Нажимаем "map local" там в "map to" выбираем файл с измененным пакетом, таким образом ответ сервера charles будет менять на этот файл.